# ModelChoiceField Queryset to another OneToOne related table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I have one ModelChoiceFiled to show the users in `User` and use `queryset` to filter the users something like this:

```
forms.py
class Form(forms.Form):
    user = ModelChoiceField(queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True), empty_label='Select the user', label='User')
```

I have another `Model` that have a `OneToOneField` to the `User` model. Is a profile `Model`:

```
models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    fieltocheck = models.BooleanField()
```

But now I need that the `ModelChoiceField` check also that the field `fieldtocheck` in the `Profile` model be `False` something like `queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True, fieldtocheck=False)` I think I can solve it using `User.objects.select_related()` but I don't get **how can I do it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
user = ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(
    is_staff=True, profile__fieldtocheck=False), ...)
```